# change value's key in dictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have done as follows

```
  NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:a1,@"0",a2,@"1",a3,@"2",a4,@"3", nil];
  NSDictionary *userbtn=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dic,@"button", nil];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userbtn];
```

I want to change the key when I move the cell in tableview.
I found value of key  could't be changed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSUInteger fromRow = [sourceIndexPath row];
    NSUInteger toRow = [destinationIndexPath row];

}
```

what should I do...... in the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Key is supposed to be unique and constant for any dictionary. Keep your `dic` as value for the key `button`. You can change the value by using `setValue:forKey`.

Answer (score 0):

As vignesh said Key is supposed to be unique hence cannot be changed but its content can be changed:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:a1,@"0",a2,@"1",a3,@"2",a4,@"3", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *userbtn=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dic,@"button", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userbtn];
```

Now

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
  NSUInteger fromRow = [sourceIndexPath row];
  NSString *fromstr = [[userbtn objectForKey:@"button"]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fromRow]]; // firstly take content at index before interchanging

  NSUInteger toRow = [destinationIndexPath row];
  NSString *tostr = [[userbtn objectForKey:@"button"]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",toRow]]; // firstly take content at index before interchanging

 [[userbtn objectForKey:@"button"] setObject:fromstr forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",toRow]]; //interchange value but key is same

 [[userbtn objectForKey:@"button"] setObject:tostr forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",fromRow]];//interchange value but key is same

}
```

Comment: en... Thanks a lot.   I made a mistake, I forgot the NSMutableDictionary.  I stored data in NSDictionary...So ...many methods are limited.

Comment: You just swap fromRow with toRow.    And what about the data between from and to.   It let me in trouble.   dictionary is not as flexible as array.......just because it's data owns a  key.......

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSDictionary *mydic=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object Zero",@"0",@"Object One",@"1",@"Object Two",@"2",@"Object Three",@"3", nil];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mydic forKey:@"MyDictionary"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

                // then for replacing values
            [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyDictionary"] mutableCopy] setObject:@"Object DOUBLE Zero" forKey:@"0"];
                // above code will replace string object @"Object Zero" to @"Object DOUBLE Zero" for key @"0"
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```